# how does back_inserter determine the type of the container

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I can't understand how does `back_inserter` knows the type of the container to return.

My "investigation" started with [this page](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/). There you will see `std::back_inserter` defined as

```
template <class Container>
  back_insert_iterator<Container> back_inserter (Container& x);
```

There is also a sample code:

```
// back_inserter example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::back_inserter
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo,bar;
  for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
  { foo.push_back(i); bar.push_back(i*10); }

  std::copy (bar.begin(),bar.end(),back_inserter(foo));

  std::cout << "foo contains:";
  for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it = foo.begin(); it!= foo.end(); ++it )
      std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The line that I can't understand is

```
std::copy (bar.begin(),bar.end(),back_inserter(foo));
```

Shouldn't the line be

```
std::copy (bar.begin(),bar.end(),back_inserter<std::vector<int>>(foo));
```

Obviously it shouldn't 'cause the code runs. So how does `back_inserter` know the type of the container to use for "back inserting". What am I missing?

Comment: Would it help to consider `template <class T> back_insert_iterator<T> back_inserter (T& x);`? You have a templates. When you declare a class of type `T` (e.g. `std::vector<int>` in `std::vector<int> foo,bar;`) template deduction can determine the proper type from the  class instance, e.g.. `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: What David says. Here's the [reference for template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). Might be a bit dry and formal reading, but the examples should help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: `std::copy` is also a templated function, you don't have to specify the types for that either

Answer (score 1):

This feature called type deduction and it is the base of modern c++ according to this book : https://g.co/kgs/JTi2Vd